# Using Cookie and Basic Authorization Middleware side-by-side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a project that need to support two `Authentication types Cookies` and `Basic`.
For this purpose i am using a custom BasicAuthenticationMiddleware and `.NET Core` `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware`.

The problem is that i cant use them both selectively.

Now to support both i could extend `BasicAuthenticationMiddleware` by deriving it from `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` and use my custom logic to make decisions on how to authenticate.

The question is would that be a correct approach or there is another standard way to have this implemented ?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't understand your actual case. If you want to use two aythentication middleware you can do it by limiting scheme. Take a look at https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.html  If this doesn't solve your problem please post detail about what you want.

Comment: Oh, it looks like scheme can be selected , haven't noticed that! Thanks.